# ¿Como puedo posicionar unos divs a la izquierda y otro a la derecha con FlexBox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

me gustaria saber como podria posicionar divs con flexbox de manera que (por ejemplo) a la izquierda esté tanto el logo como los links de una barra de navegación y a la izquierda un texto "Menu". He intentado hacerlo con justify-self y de otras maneras, pero ninguna me funciona.

El resultado que busco es el siguiente:

[image: Este es el resultado que busco.]

Este es mi código:

```
<nav>
<div class="main">
    <div class="logo">
        <h1>sidney.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
        <a href="#" class="link"> Work</a>
        <a href="#" class="link"> About</a>
        <a href="#" class="link"> Help</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-btn">
        <h1>Menu</h1>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: y tu código CSS?

Comment: Por favor lee el artículo [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), recuerda que debes de proporcionar un ejemplo que se pueda reproducir, al momento, para responder tu pregunta alguien tendría que trabajar de más y dar una respuesta mucho más amplia de lo necesaria, ¡Edita tu pregunta!, esto te ayudará a encontrar respuestas más fácilmente

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 2):

Usa flex-grow en el menu (zona central)

```html
<style>
.main{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.links{
  flex-grow:1;
}
</style>

<nav>
<div class="main">
    <div class="logo">
        <h1>sidney.</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="links">
        <a href="#" class="link"> Work</a>
        <a href="#" class="link"> About</a>
        <a href="#" class="link"> Help</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu-btn">
        <h1>Menu</h1>
    </div>
    
</div>
</nav>
```